# How to avoid mysql from locking ALL tables from SELECT ... INNER JOIN ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two mysql tables:

```
tbl_jobs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    status ENUM("runnable", "running", "finished"),
    server_id INTEGER
)

tbl_servers (
    is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

I have a lot of clients that connect, take one job for a particular server that is `runnable` and set it to `running`.

Here is how I currently do it (in stored procedure):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_JOB(serverName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE jobId INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT id FROM tbl_jobs j INNER JOIN tbl_servers s on j.server_id=s.id
              WHERE j.state='runnable' AND s.server_name=serverName
              ORDER BY job_id ASC LIMIT 1
              INTO jobId FOR UPDATE;
    IF IFNULL(jobId, 0) = 0 THEN
        SELECT 0;
    END IF;
    UPDATE tbl_jobs SET state='running' WHERE job_id=jobId;
    SELECT jobId;
END $$
```

That works just fine, **but** when number of concurrent clients become large (hundreds), I see that there is a big lock congestion going on `tbl_servers` table. I understand that `FOR UPDATE` statement locks all of the tables, but I'm actually using `tbl_servers` as read-only table.

**Question**: How to avoid lock congestion (i.e. locking at all) on `tbl_servers`?

The one thing I can think of is to separate my query into two - first convert server name to id and then query just `tbl_jobs`, but in my real application one server name can have many ids (I know it sounds odd, but I've just simplified my application here for illustration). So the second query on `tbl_jobs` would require prepared statement.

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

The system:

- MySQL 5.1.67 on Amazon RDS
- All tables are InnoDb
- I do have an index on `tbl_jobs.server_id`

Comment: why do you need the `INNER JOIN`? there is no real need for this in your code. What about `servername`? you didn't use it in your code, why do you pass this? I don't think, this is your real code

Comment: Fixed to utilize the `serverName` - that was the obvious mistype. Thanks! P.S. Of course its not a real code. Its an extract from the real application that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should avoid the locking on table `tbl_servers`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_JOB(serverName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE jobId INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

    -- get the server id's
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_srvID 
    SELECT id
    INTO srvID 
    FROM tbl_servers
    WHERE name = serverName;

    SELECT id 
    INTO jobId 
    FROM tbl_jobs 
    WHERE state='runnable'

      AND server_id IN ( SELECT id FROM tmp_srvID ) 

    ORDER BY job_id ASC 
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE;

    DROP TABLE tmp_srvID;

    IF IFNULL(jobId, 0) = 0 THEN
        SELECT 0;
    ELSE
        UPDATE tbl_jobs SET state='running' WHERE job_id=jobId;
        SELECT jobId;
    END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a big overhead of creating temporary table for each request?

Comment: no it is not such a big overhead because temp table is build in memory